# Print output includes 'None'

Tags: python

```
def backwards_alphabet(curr_letter):
    if curr_letter == 'a':
        print(curr_letter)
    else:
        print(curr_letter)
        prev_letter = chr(ord(curr_letter) - 1)
        backwards_alphabet(prev_letter)

starting_letter = input()

print (backwards_alphabet(starting_letter)) #this is the code i wrote
```

The output includes "None" but I have no idea why.
[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8um.png)

Answer (score 1):

The function `print` takes a parameter - you are giving it the *result* of `backwards_alphabet(starting_letter)`.

Since you aren't explicit about what `backwards_alphabet()` returns  - which you do would with by including `return 'this is what I am returning'`, it will return `None` by default.

So, you are calling `print(None)` and it prints 'None'.

Since your function `backwards_alphabet()` already has all of the printing within it, you don't want to do `print(backwards_alphabet(...))`, you just want to call `backwards_alphabet(...)` by itself.